# google checkout radio button under Payment Information in magento

Tags: php, magento, google-checkout, magento-1.6

i'm using magento 1.6.2.

i need to add google checkout radio button under Payment Information in magento because i need that to be working here exactly like paypal radio button.....

Google checkout api already available in magento by default but after enable it from backend google checkout button only shows in cart instead of one page checkout under Payment information portion (step 4)

i apply the following code in methods.phtml file at line 59:

```
<?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('googlecheckout/link')->setTemplate('googlecheckout/link.phtml')->toHtml(); ?>
```

Path: \app\design\frontend\base\default\template\checkout\onepage\payment\methods.pthml

it shows simple button but button not working and not redirecting to google checkout page with selected products i think it need forms elements......

Can anyone tell me how to insert radio button like paypal here instead of button for google checkout......

thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Enable googlecheckout in backend;

Find the `Payment.php` in `Model` folder, set the value of `$_canUseCheckout` to `true`;

Now you'll get a radio, but there will be many problems, enjoy it.